# Color Palette for All types of Color Blindness

Tags: color-blindness, infographic

I am trying to design an infographic that is colorful and informative. At the same time, people who are colorblind should be able to view it.

[Color-blindness website](http://www.color-blindness.com/coblis-color-blindness-simulator/) allows you to view images with normal vision and different type of color-blindness.

When I my computer program's default "colorblind safe" colors, the image is visible to people with some types of color blindness and not others.

Please tell me where I can find a palette of all colors that are visible to those with normal vision and all different types of color blindness.

Thank you

[image]

Comment: Mandatory link to ColorBrewer when someone asks about color blindness: http://colorbrewer2.org/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The key thing while designing for color blindness is that [your colors should provide enough contrast](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/visual-audio-contrast-without-color.html) to allow people with [monochromatic vision to distinguish between shades since they cant see colors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monochromacy). However there are some general guidelines while designing with color to handle color blindness.To quote [this article](http://www.somersault1824.com/tips-for-designing-scientific-figures-for-color-blind-readers/)

> But there are more approaches you could follow to avoid the color
>   blindness pitfall:
>
> 1. Avoid lesser-known bad color combinations: green & brown, blue & purple, green & blue, light green & yellow, blue & grey, green & grey,
>      green & black;
> 2. Don’t use color combinations at all, but work with different shades of the same color. In other words make your figures monochrome;
> 3. Use a high enough contrast. Contrast is something that most color blind people still can perceive very well;
> 4. Use textures instead of colors;

The above mentioned article also suggests this color palette for people with color blindness

[image]

That

Comment: Use textures? What a concept!

Comment: @Rhonda Textures aren't always an option.  Line graphs are one example - particularly ones that can't (for technical reasons) use points/shapes.

Comment: Can someone confirm whether the RGB for 13 is correct? I was going to use a blue(10) and orange(13) combination and `13 219 209 0` is giving me yellow. (Color `14 36 255 36` shows green, which is correct. I'm not color blind afaik)

Answer (score 14):

The problem with your question is that there are [a few different types of colour blindness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_blindness) and each of them perceive colours in different ways to the point that there are no 'colour' pallets that will be common to all.

Instead, you need to focus on 'contrast'. You should be aiming to achieve delineation by contrast rather than colour where it is needed.

Another tool you might want to try is the [Color Contrast Analyzer](https://www.paciellogroup.com/resources/contrastanalyser/)

If you are still struggling then you are probably trying to use too many colours. Reduce your pallet to three sympathetic colours that contrast well with each other under colour blindness tests and restrict your design to just those colours.

Comment: In addition to different types of color blindness, people with the *same* type of color blindness can perceive color differently. Designing "to Deuteranopia" doesn't mean everyone with that condition will see the colors the same way. People with "normal" color vision don't necessarily see the same color you do. So, as Andrew suggests, contrast is the appropriate target.